# Delete specific character range in sed with special characters

Tags: bash, sed

My response I am trying to tidy up is:

> ServerID response:142[90m[39mtestRuntime

I am trying to make it format in the following manner

> ServerID response:142 testRuntime

I believe [90m and [39 are some control characters from another CLI tool as they appear as empty spaces when I do not add:
`tr -dc '[:print:]` before echo'ing the response.

I have built the following sed command but it removes an additional M in the testRuntime:

```
tr -dc '[:print:]' | sed 's/[\<\[90m\[39m\>]//g'
```

How would I go about making the exact match command including special characters but only if the whole sequence matches?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `sed 's/\[90m\[39m//g'`, the problem is that you placed the whole pattern into the bracket expression, and used word boundaries where they should not be.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you very much this has solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer square brackets in `[\<\[90m\[39m\>]` form a *bracket expression* that matches a single char that is defined in it. Just removing the brackets won't solve the problem as you are using `\<` and `\>` word boundaries that are not meant to be used here as the `[90m[39m` must be removed in *any* context.

Use

```
sed 's/\[90m\[39m//g'
```

This will remove any number of `[90m[39m` on a line, everywhere in the file.